# How can I match two distribution to make them not statistically different?

Tags: distributions, mean, standard-deviation, histogram

apologies for the weirdly formulated question.

I have two distributions, X1 (blue histograms) and Y1 (yellow). They are statistically different.
I need to extract a subsample from Y1 (let's call it Y2) that would show no statistical difference with X1.

Is it something doable?
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: There is no general definition of "statistically different" There is more than one way to measure this, and it will depend on how exactly you measure "statistical difference". Also it depends on what size of a subsample you have in mind. There are situations in which it is impossible. For example if X1 has 30% below 3000 and Y1 doesn't have anything below 3000 (not visible in the image), the only way is to draw a sample of size 1 or 2, say, that is statistically indistinguishable from pretty much anything.

Answer (score 1):

How is this different from a sample from X1? If X and Y are simply sets of numbers, then then is no difference.

Maybe your question is analogous to this: X is a set of women, Y a set of men, and the histogram shows their heights (men are on average taller, but my wife is taller than me). So perhaps you want a subsample of men, whose height are statistically indistinguishable from the distribution of women's heights.

If this is the question you are asking, then you will have to limit the sample size, since on the left the ratio between the count of blue instances and the count of yellow instances becomes large. With a large sample, a statistical test can detect that.

I suggest that your sampling procedure is to iterate this approach:

1. Select a member of the blue distribution
2. If its value is greater than 3400, with probability equal to the ratio between the length of the yellow bar and the blue bar for this value, discard it and repeat.
3. Otherwise, add it to the sample.
4. Apply a statistical test to see whether the sample can be distinguished from the yellow distribution (Wilcoxons's, unless you are willing to assume the true distributions are normal).
5. If the test passes, continue.
6. Otherwise stop here, and discard the largest value in the sample to make the test pass again.

Comment: Yes,that is exactly the question I meant to ask. Thank you.
My subsample would then have values > 3400 with probability different than the ratio in point 2. correct?

Comment: For members with a value where the frequency of the blue set is greater than then frequency of the yellow set, you can discard some members to match the distributions. For members where the yellow distribution is more common this is not possible so you take them all. So you can't make a sample that is both big and statistically indistinguishable. But you can make small ones.